# What class has access to my methods?

Tags: java, object, methods, nested

My question today is about creating an object, and what other classes with have access to its methods. I am trying to learn about threading, but since JPanels don't support threads I have gotten all confused.

I create a simplified class like this:

```
public class MyMethodClass {
    public MyMethodClass () {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
    }
    public void MyMethod() {
        //do something with the variables
    }
}
```

so I now have a new class object called myClass (MyClass is another class, its content not important). As they are all public, does `myClass` have access to `MyMethod`?

If not, is there a way to pass a copy `MyMethodClass` to `myClass` so that it can use `myMethod`, knowing that `MyMethodClass` created `myClass` in the first place?

If the class `MyClass` was a nested class, does it get access to `MyMethod`?

Comment: If your nested MyClass is non-static, then an instance of MyClass will have a reference to the outer class' this.  So in this case, yes, it can access its parent's instance methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MyClass` will not be able to access methods within `MyMethodClass` unless it creates an instance of it and in this case, that's a bad idea.

You could could pass `MyClass` an instance of `MyMethodClass` via its constructor or a setter method, but you'd actually be better using a common interface, which would decouple the two classes and improve its reusability

Start by defining the contract between the two class (as an interface)...

```
public interface SomeMethods {
    public void MyMethod();
}
```

Add the ability to pass an implementation of `SomeMethods` to `MyClass` via it's constructor or setter method...

```
public class MyClass {
    private SomeMethods someMethods;
    public MyClass(SomeMethods someMethods) {
        this.someMethods = someMethods;
    }

    public void someWork() {
        someMethods.MyMethod();
    }
}
```

Have `MyMethodClass` implement the `SomeMethods` interface and pass a reference of itself to `MyClass`

```
public MyMethodsClass implements SomeMethods {
    public MyMethodClass () {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void MyMethod() {
        //do something with the variables
    }
}
```

Just beware, it's generally not considered a good idea to pass `this` to other classes or methods from within the constructor, as the state of the object may not be fully realised and some value that the methods/classes rely on may not yet be initialised.